# In a mathematical formula with “ max ” sign, how can I take the derivative and make the derivative zero to obtain the local minimum of the variable?

Tags: matrix-calculus, nonlinear-optimization, lagrange-multiplier

$$\begin{equation}\begin{split}\mathbf{W}^{(k+1)}&=\text{argmin}_{\mathbf{W}}\left\|\mathbf{F}-\mathbf{A\mathbf{W}}^{(k)}\right\|_F^2+\frac{\alpha_1}{2}\left\|\mathbf{B}\mathbf{W}^{(k)}-\mathbf{W}_\text{Air}+\frac{1}{\alpha_1}\mathbf{\Lambda}\right\|_F^2\\&+\frac{\alpha_2}{2}\left(\left\|\max\left(\frac{\Phi_1}{\alpha_2}+\left(\mathbf{W}^{(k)}-\mathbf{E}\right),0\right)\right\|_F^2-\frac{\left\|\Phi_1\right\|_F^2}{\alpha_2^2}\right)\\&+\frac{\alpha_3}{2}\left(\left\|\max\left(\mathbf{W}^{(k)}-\frac{\Phi_2}{\alpha_3},0\right)\right\|_F^2-\frac{\left\|\Phi_2\right\|_F^2}{\alpha_3^2}\right)\end{split}\end{equation}\label{1}\tag{1}$$
where

- $\mathbf{W}$, $\mathbf{F}$,$\mathbf{A}$,$\Phi_{1}$,$\Phi_2,\mathbf{E}, \mathbf{\Lambda},\mathbf{B},\mathbf{W}_\text{Air}$  are matrices ($\mathbf{W}_\text{Air}$ has nothing to do with $\mathbf{W}$, despite the similarity of their symbols), and
- $\alpha_1,\alpha_2 $ and $\alpha_3$ are scalars.

I need to determine $\mathbf{W}^{(k+1)}$ in such a way that Formula \eqref{1} above reach the local minimum. I am inclined to directly differentiate the formula respect to $\mathbf{W}^{(k+1)}$ and then equate the found derivative to 0, but I am at a loss for the $\max$ sign in the formula. How should I derive this formula? How should I Find the local minimum of $\mathbf{W}^*$?

Comment: Why do you think max or min values must always be directly accessible to the methods of calculus? Think about trying to finding a minimum of $|x|$ that way.

Comment: You could express your objective function in terms of the function $h(u) = \| \max(u,0) \|_F^2$. (The max is taken componentwise.) The function $h$ is differentiable and you can find a formula for its derivative. Then you can use the chain rule to find the derivative of your objective function. This would allow you to use gradient descent or an accelerated gradient descent method to minimize the objective function.

Comment: @littleO Thanks a lot, I think i got it.